# Excel - Date Time Format ; If time is PM add a day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel I currently have data in date time format

For example: "11/10/2007  8:40:58 PM"

I am trying to extract the date and if the time is PM, I add a day.
if the time is AM, the date remains the same.

So since the time is  8:40:58 PM I would want 12/10/2007.

Is there a way in excel to do such a thing using formulas?

Comment: How would i extract the time so that if it is PM you add a day?

Comment: Use the formula pnuts has given you

Comment: Sorry maybe my format is wrong however, when I click on the cell it is
"11/10/2007  8:40:58 PM"
So the PM and AM is not a string but from the formatting

Comment: The AM or PM is probably after parsing. So not the Value2 or the display value but rather what Excel understands it as. @pnuts wouldnt `ROUND()` just give you the day part of the excel time-code and drop the time?

Comment: @pnuts Ahh, you are right. I would suggest you make this into an answer as it is a more efficient way than my approach below. Regards.

Comment: @pnuts I would want just  12/10/2007

Comment: @absundo pnuts suggestion will provide you with that. Using your example "11/10/2007 8:40:58 PM" Excel parses this to `39396.8617824074` which is how many days from a set date (1/0/1900). The fraction part represents the time of day (or fractions of a day). if you apply `=ROUND(39396.8, 0)` you get 39397 or "12/10/2007" in excel date time formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider using the following formula. This uses the fact that in Excel in its date-time code uses 1 to represent a full day and fractions to represent the time. If timestamp is in `A1` then:

```
=INT(A1)+IF((A1-INT(A1))>=0.5,1,0)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

```
=IF(A1>0.5, A1+1, A1)
```

[image]

In order to have it only return the date right click on column B, select "Format" the take your pick.

[image]

Comment: This would not represent a solution as the OP wants to drop the time information and just add another day (or not) to the date.

Comment: @pnuts Wow, don't know where my math skills are at ;p. You are right, I was missing doing `INT(A1)` for the initial value. I have corrected my answer appropriately. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I totally agree though that your answer was the best and still suggest you should make it an answer. Regards,